# Send parameter to Home controller Index action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

What my requirement is;
if I type www.mysite.com - it will load the front page.
But if I type www.mysite.com/john - it will return john's profile page.

John's profile is originally located in /Profile/John and this works fine. But the requirement is www.mysite.dom/John.

I am trying many ways with NO success. Would be nice if anyone can help me out.
cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define two routes.

First to `"/Profile/{name}"`, then to `"/{name}"`, pointing to the same action.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same controller and have routes setup to respond to parameters, you can setup your routes like this too

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Meeting",
                url: "{name}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "Home",
                    action = "Welcome"
                }
            );
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url:"",
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "Home",
                    action = "Index"
                }
            );
```

My HomeController looks like

```
        public void Welcome(string name)
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```